# Can't find a match

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a nested arrays with pairs of numbers:

```
_open = [[8,15], [9,16]];
```

from which i want to find a match using ArrayUtilities.findMatchIndex but it always returns -1 when looking for an element array. For example:

```
ArrayUtilities.findMatchIndex(_open, [8, 15])
```

I'm wondering if it is possible for AS3 to compare arrays, because comparing other types (strings, numbers, etc) just work fine

Here's findMatchIndex():

```
public static function findMatchIndex(aArray:Array, oElement:Object, ...rest):Number {
  var nStartingIndex:Number = 0;
  var bPartialMatch:Boolean = false;
  if(typeof rest[0] == "number") {
    nStartingIndex = rest[0];
  }    
  else if(typeof rest[1] == "number") {
    nStartingIndex = rest[1];
  }
  if(typeof rest[0] == "boolean") {
    bPartialMatch = rest[0];
  }
  var bMatch:Boolean = false;
  for(var i:Number = nStartingIndex; i < aArray.length; i++) {
    if(bPartialMatch) {
      bMatch = (aArray[i].indexOf(oElement) != -1);
    }
    else {
      bMatch = (aArray[i] == oElement);
    }
    if(bMatch) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing other types (strings, numbers, etc) works fine, because they are so-called primitives, and are compared by values. Arrays, though, are objects, therefore they are compared by reference. Basically it means that `[8,15]` != `[8,15]`.

One way around it is replacing this line...

```
else {
  bMatch = (aArray[i] == oElement);
}
```

... with something like this ...

```
else {
  bMatch = compareElements(aArray[i], oElement);
}
```

... where `compareElements` will try to check its arguments' types first, and if they're objects, will compare their values.